# Force opening a webpage with Internet Explorer

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, shellexecute

I need to open a webpage using Internet Explorer even if it is not the predefined Browser.

(e.g. Chrome is predefined but I want to open `www.ThisRunsOnlyOnInternetExplorer.com`.

How to achieve this? Of course with `ShellExecute` I know how to open the default browser.

Of course this must work on all Windows operating systems and all internet explorer versions so I cannot harcode a path to `iexplorer.exe`.

Can you suggest a solution?

Note: if there is a way to get the path to iexplorer.exe with some API may be the trick is gtet that path and then use ShellExecute to run

```
PATH_TO_INTERNET_EXPLORER_EXE www.ThisRunsOnlyOnInternetExplorer.com
```

Comment: Isn't iexplore.exe on the path in every Windows version? Then you can just use ShellExecute `iexplore www.ThisRunsOnlyOnInternetExplorer.com`.

Comment: In my Windows 7 machine it is not on the path

Comment: @Matthijs you were right anyway David clearified my problem

Comment: Without disputing your need to do this, since you don't mention the details, please know that this is going to be quite annoying for some of your users. People choose their browser for a reason, and whenever you override their choice, you increase their adrenaline flow and add to their daily stress level. Please be aware of that, seriously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use a fully qualified path. When IE is installed it registers itself in the [App Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) registry. Consequently you just need to send `iexplore.exe` to `ShellExecute()`.

**Note:** `CreateProcess()` does not use the App Paths mechanism so you must use `ShellExecute()` rather than `CreateProcess()`.

Comment: ah... I see `ShellExecute(Handle,'open', PChar('iexplore.exe'), PChar (' www.ThisRunsOnlyOnInternetExplorer.com'),  nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)` works. But if I had to run this from the command line what I should do? because from command line `iexplore.exe www.ThisRunsOnlyOnInternetExplorer.com` doesn't work  ;

Comment: @user When you do this from cmd.exe this does not go via the shell and via App Paths. It goes straight to CreateProcess. If you do it from the Windows Run dialog then the shell is back in play. But you asked how to do it in a Windows program and so the issue with cmd.exe is incidental.

Comment: Curiosity: The MSDN documentation says that the if the application can open URLs directly, the `UseUrl` DWORD value must be defined and set to '1', otherwise the document will be downloaded and a path to the local copy passed to the application. On my machine, the entry for `iexplore.exe` doesn't define `UseUrl`!.

Comment: @David thanks i didn't know this "subtle" difference between cmd and run. I never realized that ShellExecute was doing the work done by Windows Run.

Comment: Raymond Chen already talked about the UseUrl option: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/30/10181645.aspx  quite interesting!

Answer (score 1):

try something like ShellExecute(handle, "open", "%PROGRAMFILES%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "http://google.com", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

I think programfiles is set for all windows.

EDIT: I deleted the other stuff, because I didn't quite get the question.

Answer (score 1):

I use to have the same problem as you. I have Google Chrome as my defaut browser and want to force using IE for some specific URL. I found a solution that work perfectly for me. I use ShellExecuteEx and I specify the file type as a IE.HTTP or IE.HTTPS.

I hope it help.

FillMemory(@vShellExec, SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo), 0);
vShellExec.cbSize := SizeOf(vShellExec);
vShellExec.fMask := SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME or SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or 
  SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI; 
vShellExec.Wnd := 0;
vShellExec.lpFile := PChar(asURL);
vShellExec.nShow := SW_ShowNormal;
vShellExec.lpClass := PChar(sFileType); // use IE.HTTP or IE.HTTPS 
vShellExec.lpVerb  := PChar('Open');

ShellExecuteEx(@vShellExec);